# how to get the Id of last row deleted from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the last Id using max(Id) function where Id is the primary key. My code works well unless I delete last row from the table, because when I delete last row then that Id is still preserved and in that case max(Id) will retrieve the last row Id but not that Id which is deleted from the table.

Is there any function which retrieve the last row deleted Id. I have seen some posts using `scope_identity()` and `@@identity` functions to get the current Id. I have used these functions but they are not working. I am editing my code inside a dll file may be dat is creating  problem.

Comment: you seem to be doing a lot of work with .dat files.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? You're presenting us with your solution and running into a road block with it and I suspect there's something you're trying to do that is driving that solution. Take us back a step to what the need is and we may be able to present an alternative approach altogether. Are you trying to get the highest id *ever* used? Of course I can't make any promises ;).

Comment: You may want to reconsider how you're deleting the rows as well.  Best practice is to delete by primary key whenever possible so you should really have the ID before you make the delete.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SQL 2005 or above you can use OUTPUT clause to get the id for deleted row.

[Check out this link for a nice example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a TRIGGER FOR DELETE Event, and insert in a log table the deleted records.

```
CREATE TABLE LogDeletetable 
(
    ID          int           IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [datedelete] smalldatetime NOT NULL DEFAULT Getdate(),
    ExtID int
 )

CREATE TRIGGER TriggerONDELETE
ON MyTable
FOR DELETE
AS
DECLARE @ID int    
SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM deleted)    
INSERT Logtable (ExtID ) VALUES(@ID)
GO
```

Then you can query against the table myLogtable for the deleted records.

```
Select * FROM Logtable
```

Comment: And if your database supports triggers, it likely supports stored procedures -- so you could use a stored procedure to do the delete, that then returns what the ID was that it deleted.  (or do as Sonny Boy said, and use the ID for the delete in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

@@Identity and Scope_Identity() only return the most recent identity value for the *current session*.

To get the highest identity value that has *ever been assigned to a table* (even when some of them have been deleted) you can use Ident_Current

BOL describes it as follows:
IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx