# Returning a list of ids of deleted items

Tags: sql-server

I am uncertain if this is not possible or if I am just unable to find the solution.

I am trying to write a SQL stored procedure that will delete a number of items and return the list of unique identifiers for the deleted items.

By using a temporary table I can add select all the items I want to delete, add the ids to a temp table, then delete all the items with an id in the temp table then return all the ids in the temp table.

I would like to avoid doing that, is there a better approach that will delete and return all the ids without the need for a temp table, and not making multiple calls to the db?

Any ideas welcome, and if there is a similar post please direct me. (I was unable to find one)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the Id of last row deleted from SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731255/how-to-get-the-id-of-last-row-deleted-from-sql-table)

Comment: have a look at OUTPUT clause, it can be used with DELETE to return deleted data

Comment: I cannot use a trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below an example of what you want to achieve:

```
create table your_table 
(
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key, 
    value varchar(100)
);

insert into your_table (value) values
('hello'), ('from'), ('Mars'), ('!!!!');

create proc dbo.deleteByChar
(
    @char char(1)
) as
begin
    delete from your_table
    output deleted.id --> OUTPUT clause as @Vishal_Gajjar suggested
    where value like '%' + @char + '%';
end
```

Usage:

```
select * from your_table;
exec dbo.deleteByChar 'o';
select * from your_table;
```

Output:

```
id  value
---------
1   hello
2   from
3   Mars
4   !!!!

id
--
1
2

id  value
---------
3   Mars
4   !!!!
```

Comment: This is nice, but still has a second table, no way to avoid that?

Comment: What if you use "output deleted.id" instead of "output deleted.id into @deleted_ids"

Comment: @Vishal Gajjar you are perfectly right - implemented!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using trigger, there is `deleted` virtual table where you can find the id-s. Note that in case of `UPDATE` the id-s will exist in `deleted` table again. To detect `UPDATE` you can join `inserted` table.